# Is AWS AppSync available for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, aws-appsync

Although I see the SDK here

**Github :** https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/tree/master/sdk/src/Services/AppSync

**Nuget :** https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.AppSync

I do not see any sample apps using the AppSync for `Xamarin` or even `.NET` on Google. Is this really available or just a `placeholder Nuget module`?

If this is available, can anyone point me to a sample code?

Thank

Comment: The C# library wraps the AppSync GraphQL REST-based endpoints, it is up to you to write the queries, structure the data, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For the GraphQL queries, I can easily write my own C# code. However, the AppSync SDK is contains many other features such as offline syncing and event subscriptions for realtime data binding. Although the code seems to be there, they look like pretty much empty and I cannot find any samples or docs on the web, weird!

Comment: One of the big things about the AppSync "native" client APIs (iOS,Android, React, etc..) is that they are based upon code generation of your GraphGL models in the build process to provide all the heavy lifting / bootstrapping. As everything is based on GraphQL (subscriptions/sync/etc...) assumably against DynamoDB it is much much easier to use native mobile development for iOS/Android then Xamarin currently. AppSync is really new in terms of production, so maybe the C# API will include MSBuild targets in the future to make it on par with Java/Swift/React-javascript/browser-javascript...

Comment: Thanks SushiHangover! That explains it. I could see that the iOS, for example, auto generates an API class (using a tool) and same for the Android. Obviously this is not yet supported for Xamarin projects. Without it, I assume you cannot do much. (and now I am more convinced that the Nuget library(.net SDK) https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.AppSync is pretty much a placeholder. For now, I'll revert back to Azure offline syncing and SignalR for realtime messaging. Thanks for the info, that really helped!